# How to write JUnit test case for pdf file creating functionality

Tags: java, junit, mockito

How to write JUnit test case which generates file and placing at some temp location.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/generateSalesReport", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/pdf")
public void generateSalesReport(
            @RequestBody SalesReportVO salesReportVO,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
                                 response) {
           SalesService.salesService(salesReportVO, request,  response);
}

//Service: SalesService.java
public void salesService(SalesReportVO salesReportVO,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
                                 response){
         //access the database and create a PDF and save at temp location
         //fileNameReport -- it is the newly created file name which is returned to Angular page as response text and other get method open this file in browser new tab
         response.getWriter().write(fileNameReport);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Plz. use the editor functions to mark code as code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which can be compiled and tested by others. Also include the unit test you currently have and what you are trying to do. Additionally explain where you stuck or what the problem is.